# Using Java’s Marvin framework with Android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, marvin-framework

I have created an activity captures an image through Camera and now I have the image in `Bitmap` format which I want to pass to this plugin class from here:
The function looks like this:

```
public void process(MarvinImage imageIn, MarvinImage imageOut, MarvinAttributes attrOut, MarvinImageMask mask, boolean preview) {
```

Now how do I pass these arguments?

It first asks for `MarvinImage` so how can I convert my `Bitmap` to MarvinImage? And what are rest of the arguments?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the android compatible version of Marvin was not released yet. It's under development. You can follow the project releases on its [Freecode](https://freecode.com/projects/marvin) page.

If you want to understand how Marvin works, what are these arguments, take a look at the [Tutorials](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/tutorials.html) available on the project website.